# how to optimize this code (Double loop in python)?

Tags: python, loops, numpy, opencv

I had this code:

```
for x in range(len(img)):
    for y in range(len(img[0])):
        if img[x][y]==255 :
            imgblur[x][y]=imggray[x][y]
```

I improved with this:

```
i, j = np.where(img == 255)
for x in range(i.shape[0]):
    imgblur[i[x]][j[x]]=imggray[i[x]][j[x]]
```

Is there a way to improve more (Faster loop)?

Comment: `imgblur = np.where(img == 255, imggray, imgblur)`?

Comment: Hell yeah, you got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `np.where()` which says:

`if img==255 then imgblur = imgray
             else imgblur = imgblur`

```
nx, ny = 5, 10
img = np.random.randint(255, size=(nx, ny))
imgblur = np.random.uniform(0,1.0,size=(nx, ny))
imggray = np.random.uniform(0,1.0,size=(nx, ny))

imgblur =   np.where(img==255,imggray,imgblur)
imgblur
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just try:

```py
imgblur[imggray==255]=255
```

example code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('imgs/car1.jpg')

imggray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

imgblur = np.zeros_like(imggray)
imgblur[imggray > 200] = 255

cv2.imshow('imggray', imggray)
cv2.imshow('imgblur', imgblur)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

imggray:
[image: imggray]

imgblur:
[image]